# Can someone tell me how to find out the date and time when the user connected to the voice channel?

Tags: discord.js

Can someone tell me how to find out the date and time when the user connected to the voice channel?

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
        let userConfig;
    if(oldMember.channel && !newMember.channel)
    {
        let date = new Date(oldMember.member.joinedTimestamp);
        let date1 = new Date();
        console.log(date)
        console.log(date1)
    }
    else{
        
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if discord stores it anywhere, you can take a look at the docs. I couldn't find it. Anyway you can try to cache the join times and dates yourself.